# About register "BeanPostProcessor" use"BeanFactoryPostProcessor"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

> When I use "BeanFactoryPostProcessor" to register "BeanPostProcessor" and at the same time use AutoConfiguration to wire up my defined "BeanFactoryPostProcessor", I found that my "BeanPostProcessor" execution order is after "@PostConstruct", I am curious why, and please what is good way to deal with

> The key code is as follows
> JDK17\SpringBoot3.0.0-M3

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MapstructFactory implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final MapstructRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof Converter) {
            registry.addConverter((Converter<?, ?>) bean);
        }
        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MapstructFactoryRegister implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private final MapstructRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
         beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(new MapstructFactory(registry));
    }

}
```

```java
@AutoConfiguration
public class MapstructAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MapstructFactoryRegister mapstructFactoryRegister(MapstructRegistry registry) {
        return new MapstructFactoryRegister(registry);
    }
}
```

Comment: `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` should be defined in `public static` bean methods so that they can operate very early on on the lifecycle instead of during the lifecycle. However I don't really get this contraption and seems overly complex. Just auto wire a list of `Converter` into the `MapstructRegistry` instead of doing this. It all seems overly complex/engineered due to not understanding how things work.

Comment: > I also think the design is too complicated, thank you for your answer, I will try to solve it in other ways